# Get Browser Information in MySQL Procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

Is it possible to get browser information in a **PROCEDURE** via MySQL code?

Without having to pick up via backend code and pass as parameter. That is, does MySQL have any function that returns browser information?

Comment: MySQL is not a web server, no browser is going to connect to it directly, therefore it cannot have any function or procedure to return any browser information.

Comment: OK! Thanks, I'm using procedures, so I'll pass the information as parameter. I just wanted to be sure before I could not get this information in Mysql.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

MySQL runs at server side whereas browser info is sent from `client` side (in `request` headers). So, unless it's passed to `MySQL` stored procedure or function (via a web app or `php`), there is no way `MySQL` would `get` the browser information.

Answer (score 1):

Any browser information is going to come in the HTTP request and will need to be passed on by your backend code to your MySQL server. There is no function in MySQL that can give it to you directly because the MySQL server doesn't have access to that information.